# Sessão vs Consulta ao Banco de dados

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, session

Galera, estou em dúvida aqui.

Dentro de meu painel de controle, vou precisar pegar id do usuário, email, senha (só para alterar senha) nome, sobre nome, etc... O ideal seria salvar isso tudo em uma sessão na hora do login ou sempre que eu precisar disso, eu consulto isso diretamente no banco de dados?

Por favor, não considerem isso por ser uma pergunta que terá uma resposta baseada em opiniões. Eu preciso mesmo desse empurrão pra poder dar continuidade em meu projeto!

Agradeço.

Comment: Pense assim: se você salvar em sessão e o usuário se logar em outro computador, alterar os dados e salvar, voltar no primeiro computador, que está com os dados originais na sessão, alterar novamente e salvar. Quais deveriam ser os dados do usuário? O que ele alterou no primeiro ou no segundo computador?

Comment: Eita kkk. Mas, assim, eu vou criar um sistema de deslogar a pessoa, se outra sessão for iniciada em um lugar diferente. Mesmo sendo assim, o melhor é a consulta?

Comment: Sobre ser opinativa, depende muito de como você formula a pergunta. Você sempre pode pedir uma comparação entre duas coisas, com prós e contras, e tomar sua decisão sozinho de acordo com o seu contexto. Pedir opinião é esperar que exista uma resposta "correta". Não existe, você tem de definir o que usar baseado no que sabe, nos seus objetivos e no seu contexto específico.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existem problemas de armazenar muitos dados em sessões.

Um deles é a performance do servidor. Cada sessão que você cria no php tem o seu conteúdo serializado e quando é feita a conversão isso gera um custo. Se você tem várias sessões para serem desserializada você aumenta esse custo. E ai você soma isso para muitos usuários fuçando na sua página ao mesmo tempo...

Outra coisa é a segurança. Exite um ataque chamado [`Sesssion Hijacking`](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking) que tenta pegar os cookies criados pelo servidor. Então se você simplesmente não faz uma verificação ou autenticação com o banco a cada requisição do usuário no seu site, sua aplicação fica bastante vulnerável.

O ideal é criar uma sessão com uma hash de um id e resgatar as informações no banco desse usuário.