# Utilizar session ou utilizar banco de dados?

Tags: php

Resumo: qual alternativa iria "poupar" o servidor? Guardar um enorme array em uma session (nome, email, cpf, cidade etc) ou sempre fazer uma consulta no banco de dados (mysql) quando precisar de uma informação (considerando que a todo segundo centenas de consultas estariam sendo realizadas)?

Eu nunca precisei me preocupar com esse tipo de coisa, mas agora estou com um cliente que tem um site com mais de mil acessos simultâneos e o servidor do mesmo é péssimo (já sugeri mudanças, novos servidores/serviços e foi tudo barrado), sempre está caindo. Portanto, estou preocupado com um sistema que estou desenvolvendo. Basicamente, esse sistema lida com cadastro de usuários e consulta dos mesmos no banco de dados. Como o servidor já é ruim, não sei qual alternativa (session ou consultas ao db) seria a "menos pior".

Sobre a duplicata: nenhuma resposta da pergunta foi conclusiva e o autor também não se manifestou sobre nada.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Sessão vs Consulta ao Banco de dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/263748/sess%c3%a3o-vs-consulta-ao-banco-de-dados)

Comment: Inclusive, acredito que a pergunta está baseada em opiniões. Ela parece levar cada resposta de acordo com um ponto de vista diferente.

Comment: O certo mesmo é ter um servidor que comporte a aplicação. Ficar fazendo remendos meia-boca é uma forma ruim de tentar economizar (eu sei, as vezes a culpa disso é do "gerente").

Answer (score -2):

Eu recomendo a utilizar SESSION para dados pessoais do seu usuário para utilização da aplicação e somente isso, o resto seria feito por consultas ao BD mesmo.

Quanto a quantidade de usuários e acessos simultâneos é necessário um estudo para melhor performance da aplicação, sendo que se um usuário não estiver satisfeito com a apresentação do conteúdo gerando erros ou muito tempo pra ver seu conteúdo isso vai gerar insatisfação do mesmo.

Deve ser apresentado um estudo técnico para melhorias sempre.

Answer (score -3):

Olha, sendo breve.
Acredito que deve armazenar em server mesmo.
Se armazenar no banco, pode correr o risco, dependendo de algumas variáveis, de ocorrer dead lock no banco.

Com relação ao uso do servidor, se ele não está suportando, infelizmente a solução é escalar.